# Is it possible to write a function that returns multiple values in a specific format?

Tags: python, dictionary, return, dictionary-comprehension

I'm writing a function that returns two values which will form the key-value pair of a dictionary. This function will be used to create a dictionary  with dictionary comprehension. However, using dictionary comprehension the pair of values need to be provided in the format 'key: value'. To accomplish this, I have to call the function twice. Once for the key, and once for the value. For example,

```
sample_list = [['John', '24', 'M', 'English'], 
               ['Jeanne', '21', 'F', 'French'],
               ['Yuhanna', '22', 'M', 'Arabic']]

def key_value_creator(sample_list):
   key = sample_list[0]
   value = {'age': sample_list[1],
            'gender': sample_list[2], 
            'lang': sample_list[3]}

   return key, value

dictionary = {key_value_creator(item)[0]: \
              key_value_creator(item)[1] for item in sample_list}
```

As you can see, the function is called twice to generate values that can be generated in one run. Is there a way to return the values in a format that can be usable by the comprehension? If that is possible, the function need only be called once, as such:

```
dictionary = {key_value_creator(item) for item in sample_list}
```

As far as I have seen, other ways of returning multiple values is to return them in the form of a dictionary or list,

```
return {'key': key, 'value': value}
```

```
return [key, value]
```

but either way, to access them we will have to call the function twice.

```
dictionary = {key_value_creator(item)['key']: \
              key_value_creator(item)['value'] for item in sample_list}
```

```
dictionary = {key_value_creator(item)[0]: \
              key_value_creator(item)[1] for item in sample_list}
```

Is there a way to format these values so that we can send them to the dictionary comprehension statement in the format that it requires?

EDIT:
Expected Output:

```
{ 'John': {'age': '24', 'gender': 'M', 'lang': 'English'}, 
'Jeanne': {'age': '21', 'gender': 'F', 'lang': 'French'}, 
'Yuhanna': {'age': '22', 'gender': 'M', 'lang': 'Arabic'}}
```

Comment: can you post the expected output

Answer (score 5):

Just use the [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) builtin function, expecting a sequence of `(key, value)` pairs as returned by your `key_value_creator` function and making a `dict` from those:

```
>>> dict(map(key_value_creator, sample_list))
{'Jeanne': {'age': '21', 'gender': 'F', 'lang': 'French'},
 'John': {'age': '24', 'gender': 'M', 'lang': 'English'},
 'Yuhanna': {'age': '22', 'gender': 'M', 'lang': 'Arabic'}}
```

Also works with a generator expression instead of `map`:

```
>>> dict(key_value_creator(item) for item in sample_list)
```

Or use a dictionary comprehension with a nested generator expression and tuple-unpacking:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in (key_value_creator(item) for item in sample_list)}
```

Or without your `key_value_creator` function, just using a nested dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> {n: {"age": a, "gender": g, "lang": l} for n, a, g, l in sample_list}
```

Comment: I like all three of you suggestions. The second is interesting. But I'm guessing the first is the most Pythonic way to do it. Is there no way to format the return value though?

Comment: @AmosP What do you mean with "format the return value"? Format the dict in a specific way, or have the function return a value that can be used directly in a dict comprehension? In case of the latter, I'd say the 2nd approach is as close as it gets.

Comment: The latter. To have the function return a value that can be used directly.